# checking ascending order of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any SQL code to check whether the values stored in a specified column follows ascending or descending order?

For Example I want to check that ascending order in column c in this table.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not specific syntax for this.  Probably the easiest way is to  get the previous value, and then check against that.  Here is one way using correlated subqueries:

```
select name,
       (case when sum(c_prev > c) = 0 then 'All Ascending'
             else 'Oops'
        end)
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.c
              from thistable t2
              where t2.name = t.name and t2.year < t.year
              order by t2.year desc
              limit 1
             ) as c_prev
      from thistable t
     ) t
group by name;
```

Here is another method:

```
select t.name,
       (case when group_concat(c order by c) = group_concat(c order by year)
             then 'All Ascending'
             else 'Oops'
        end)
from thistable t
group by t.name;
```

This is slightly different in how it treats equal values.  Also, this is subject to string length restrictions on the length of the `group_concat()` result (which can be overridden using by changing a parameter).  But, it might be handy for some purposes.